# Citing author name or year without natbib or biblatex

Tags: citing

My university's thesis class breaks when using `natbib/biblatex`. It breaks all `\chapter*{name}` commands so that they make a chapter called * with text name in their body.  Using  `\bibliography{myRefs}` with `natbib` gives me a screwed up chapter name (*). Using `\printbibliography` with `biblatex` does the same.

Is there an easy way to get the author name or year out of a citation without using either of those packages?

I'd happily roll my own `\citeauthoryear` and `\citep` commands if it's possible.  I don't know TeX well enough to change the class file to avoid that behaviour.

Comment: Hi and welcome, instead of doing a workaround wouldn't it be easier to *fix the thesis class*?

Comment: I mean, if the car is broken i take it to the shop. I don't get a horse in front of it dragging me and the car. This might be exaggerated, but i am trying to make a point here.

Comment: To answer your question of whether or not it would be easier to fix the class, for me, definitely not.  I know enough tex to write a \citep macro, but I poked around the class file and it's totally incomprehensible to me.  Would it be better for the next guy to have a fixed template? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Well, somebody is maintaining the thing, there's gotta be a name, a mail address with the class file.

Comment: I think you give the thesis office too much credit.  The last edit in the comments is dated 1998 and the thesis office explicitly states that they won't help with technical problems...

Comment: Then i would simply suggest to make everything available, maybe even on github and send the thesis office a fixed version. Well, you have to make sure that you are actually allowed to publish the source, and/or make any changes to it. Please check that out first.

Comment: Put up on github here.  This example shows the issue and includes (I think) everything necesssary to build it.  https://github.com/benjones/brokenThesis

Comment: By the very first glance i notice [\end{enumerate} error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/553403)

Comment: Where?  I don't see any uses of enumerate in my sample.

Comment: Lines 33/34 in `thesis.tex`. If you are interested, we can have a more verbose discussion over at LaTeX-community.org, a classical discussion forum. The system here gets a bit cross about our chat, as the question is quite *difficult to handle*.

Comment: I started a thread over there.  Thanks (http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=25877)

Comment: Does the thesis class match the formatting requirements? That is, do they say your bibliography should be numbered? (Or shouldn't be or anything of that kind?)

Comment: I don't see anything in their style guide about numbering the references chapter, but in the example TOC they have, it's unnumbered.  The class is from the thesis office (without any guarantees of acceptance for using it...).

Comment: @BenJones I'm sure you'll be surprised to know that they still haven't fixed it, despite releasing a new version in May of this year. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the code the class uses for the references in a new bibheading style for `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass[Chicago]{uuthesis2e}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{uuthesis2e}{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}%
% Switch singlespace to after the heading gets printed.
  \mainheading{REFERENCES}%
  \par\removelastskip\singlespace\par\removelastskip% GBG Oct 1993
  \fixmainheadingSKIP
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{usual chapter}

In \citeyear{companion} some nice guys wrote
\citetitle{companion}~\cite{companion}.
Something else \cite{aristotle:physics}.

\printbibliography[heading=uuthesis2e]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Similarly for `natbib`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\providecommand\newblock{}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}%
% Switch singlespace to after the heading gets printed.
  \mainheading{REFERENCES}%
  \par\removelastskip\singlespace\par\removelastskip% GBG Oct 1993
  \fixmainheadingSKIP
}
```

Comment: Hah, this worked for me, thanks. The University of Utah thesis office still hasn't fixed the template. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The class is pretty old and does not provide unnumbered chapters, which are by default *starred chapters*. You can *somehow* workaround the situation by typesetting the bibliography numbered.

```
\documentclass[Chicago]{uuthesis2e}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{usual chapter}
In \citeyear{companion} some nice guys wrote
\citetitle{companion}~\cite{companion}.
\chapter*{starred chapter}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

---

You  can do the same with package natbib, which isn't near as powerful as `biblatex`. Funny thing is, you need to provide command `\newblock` as the old class does not provide this command itself.

```
\documentclass[Chicago]{uuthesis2e}
\providecommand\newblock{}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{usual chapter}
%In \citeyear{companion} some nice guys wrote
%\citetitle{companion}~
\cite{companion}.
\chapter*{starred chapter}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

---

A closer look to the class file just revealed, that the class provides the command `\mainheading` for some kind of unnumbered chapter. The original bibheading was set this way. The standard output can be seen in the following picture again using `natbib`. There is no clearpage by default.

[image: benjonesBrokenThesis]

```
\documentclass[Chicago]{uuthesis2e}
\providecommand\newblock{}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\mainheading{\bibname}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{usual chapter}
%In \citeyear{companion} some nice guys wrote
%\citetitle{companion}~
\cite{companion}.
\chapter*{starred chapter}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```