# How to specify the part of name used in \cite{} using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a Tibetan Buddhist master who is referred to as Dzogchen Khenpo Choga Rinpoche.
How can I write my `.bib` file entry, so that `biblatex` would know to

1. use `Khenpo Choga` as the part of the name displayed in `\cite{}`, e.g. `(Khenpo Choga 2012)`
2. not make any changes to the name when printing it into the bibliography list, so `Dzogchen Khenpo Choga Rinpoche`, not `Rinpoche, Dzogchen Khempo Choga`

Comment: May be You can find something useful here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233672/citing-author-name-or-year-without-natbib-or-biblatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a real solution should probably setup a tibetan name template. But for one entry you could also use additional braces and the shortauthor field:

```
\begin{filecontents}{tibetan.bib}
@article{test,
author = {{Dzogchen Khenpo Choga Rinpoche}},
year =2012,
journal={Journal},
title={Some title},
shortauthor={{Khenpo Choga}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tibetan.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cite{test}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hints for the extended name templates can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287732/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864 as well as the posts linked there.